# Restoring Deleted Folders in git

Tags: git

```
 project
  |---src
  |---main
  |---config.xml
```

i had a project folder with src having all source codes and some config files.
in src i maintained git repository and i had many commits.

Recently i wanted to have backup of config and create git repo in poject folder. and commited project with config.

Unfortunately i deleted entire folder [rm -rf *] [used many git repo and wrongly deleted here]

so i have 1 commit outside. and many commits inside src.

when i tried

```
 git reset HEAD --hard
```

it retrieved the structure and there is no files within src.  How to retrieve those files?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out     -     http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/18/restoring-a-directory-from-history.html

Comment: didn't help. only retrieved folder structure but src is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the deleted files back into your working tree using `git checkout .`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not think it is possible - though somebody please correct me if otherwise! :-)

It sounds like what you have done is (unknowingly?) added your `src` folder as an incompletely setup submodule. If you did not explicitly add your `src` folder with a trailing slash, Git would have thought that you were trying to set up a submodule (i.e. a gitlink).

```
git add src     # Tries to set up a proper submodule
git add src/    # Tracks changes in src from project
```

See this link about the [faking a submodule](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb), which is what I assume you wanted to do in the first place.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim, I pointed out that the minor difference of forgetting to include a trailing slash when you perform a `git add` will result in Git interpreting your actions as an attempt to set up a submodule. I know the OP was not inquiring about setting up submodules, but I simply wanted to make the OP aware of this nuance.

Comment: i thought it should keep track of subfolder src [git repo] too. why 's that can't be recovered?

Comment: @Dineshkumar, commit objects affecting files inside `src` are stored within the `.git` folder of `src` and *not* `project` if you did not explicitly `git add` the `src` folder with a trailing slash. Thus, once you have lost your `src` folder (i.e. along with the `.git` folder contains, which has the commits needed to reconstruct your files) I do not think it is possible to reconstruct `src` files from `project` since no commits affecting `src` files were kept in the `.git` folder of `project`.